# Python: taking lines from a text file and searching words that start with "from" and outputting those lines

Tags: python, file, variables

I'm trying to output a big file of emails and trying to pull up the lines that start with "from" in them. "Beginner Python"

> x = open('text_file.txt','w')
>
> y = input('Please enter file name followed by.txt:')
>
> print(y)
>
> for name in x:
>
> ```
> if name.startswith('From'):
>
>     xname = name[0:]
>
>     print(xname)
> ```

here is basically the output I want to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
with open('_my_file.txt', 'r') as _my_file:
    # Iterates over the lines in file
    for _ in _my_file.readlines():
        # Ignore the case while searching
        if _.casefold().startswith('from'):
            print(_)
```